# how to write raw query in yii2 using mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

```
$query=yii::$app->mongodb->createCommand('select * from recoveries_crud rec where loan_id="2811" INNER join regions r onrec.region_id=r.id')->queryall();
```

this  query giving error

> Calling unknown method: yii\mongodb\Command::queryall()

Comment: did you import the Yii namespace?
use Yii;
use yii\mongodb\Query;

Comment: yes i have imported yii\mongodb\Query

Comment: did you add yii mongodb php extension? check this link https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb

Comment: yes extension installed and yii  active record working fine.i am telling about raw query.